# Task Scheduler - Trigger another task after one task is done - Windows7

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I want a Task created in Task scheduler to trigger another task in Task scheduler after the former one is completed.

I have tried defining multiple actions but after completing first action, its never completing the second action. It shows as Task running but no output.

Basically, I run a Python script on my Desktop (i use the arguments Start in: C:\Python27) Then the texst file it creates is worked with an Macro based excel file. (the second task which is never getting done)